# Euler's Totient Function and Residue Classes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I have been working on a formula that seems to be a generalization of Euler's Totient Function and have a number of questions:

1. I have been researching online and can't seem to find this function anywhere.  I'm assuming that it is probably just in a different format.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?
2. It is pretty easy to prove the equation below when $m$ and $n$ share the same prime factors since it is equivalent to Euler's Totient Function.  Any hints on how to prove when $m$ and $n$ do not share the same prime factors?

Let $R_n =\{ a|a \in \mathbb{Z}, 1\leqq a\leqq n,gcd(a,n)=1 \}$

Let $T_n =\{a_1,a_2,...,a_k,a_1+n,a_2+n,...,a_k+n\}$

Let $g_m(n)$ represent the number of elements in $R_n$ such that $a_k+m$ also exists in $T_n$.

Let $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}...p_k^{e_k}$ represent the prime factorization of $n$.

We state that
$$g_m(n) = \prod_{p|n,p|m} p_k^{e-1}(p_k-1) \prod_{p|n,p|m\notin \mathbb{Z}} p_k^{e-1}(p_k-2) $$
where $m$ is even and $m\leqq n$

For example, let $n=20$ and $m=6$. It follows that

$$R_{20} = \{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$$
$$T_{20}=\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19,21,23,27,29,31,33,37,39\}$$
$$g_6(20)=2^1*(2-1)*5^0*(5-2)=6$$
The elements of $g_6(20)$ are $1,3,7,11,13,17$

Comment: Though it's fixable, I'm not a fan of treating $\varphi(20)$ on one hand as a tuple/ordered set and on the other as an integer.

Comment: Thanks, what would be the best way fix?

Comment: You could define a set $R_{20}$ to be the integers $x$ with $1 \leq x \leq 20$ with $\gcd(x,20)=1$.  Then $\varphi(20)$ is just $|R_{20}|$.  Of course, there's nothing special about $20$.

Comment: ok.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Starting with $37$, are the elements in your example of $T$ not too big by $10$? Also, I don't understand the notation $p|n,p|m\notin \mathbb{Z}$ in your second factor; if the second factor is supposed to range over the primes which don't divide $m$, but the third over those where $p$ does divide $m$, isn't that exactly the other way around than in your example computation of $g_6(20)$?

Comment: By the way, it sems to me that another possibly helpful way to express $g_m$ is $g_m(n) = \lbrace x \in \Bbb Z/n: x \in (\Bbb Z/n)^\times \land x+m  \in (\Bbb Z/n)^\times\rbrace$, i.e. those units whose translate by $m$ is still a unit.

Comment: Torsten, thank you very much for your comments.  I just edited the first item.  I'm working to clean up the rest of it.

Comment: @RobG Ok but then where are you stuck at following it. The [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) is about constructing the $b_j$ which is easy and from which everything simplifies.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the link on CRT.  I will review over the weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n = \prod_{j=1}^J p_j^{e_j}$ and $$g_m(n) = \sum_{l=1}^n 1_{gcd(l,n)=gcd(l+m,n)=1}$$

Using the CRT to decompose $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}/p_1^{e_1}\mathbb{Z} \times \ldots \times  \mathbb{Z}/p_j^{e_j}\mathbb{Z}, b_j \equiv 1 \bmod p_j^{e_j}, b_j \equiv 0 \bmod p_i^{e_i}$

$$g_m(n)= \prod_{j=1}^J \sum_{l_j=1}^{p_j^{e_j}}  1_{l= \sum_{i=1}^Jl_i b_i, gcd(l,p_j)=gcd(l+m,p_j)=1}= \prod_{j=1}^J \sum_{l_j=1}^{p_j^{e_j}}  1_{l= \sum_{i=1}^Jl_i b_i}\prod_{i=1}^J1_{gcd(l,p_i)=gcd(l+m,p_i)=1}
$$ $$= \prod_{j=1}^J \sum_{l_j=1}^{p_j^{e_j}}  \prod_{i=1}^J1_{gcd(l_i,p_i)=gcd(l_i+m,p_i)=1}=\prod_{j=1}^J \sum_{l_j=1}^{p_j^{e_j}}  1_{gcd(l_j,p_j)=gcd(l_j+m,p_j)=1}$$ $$=\prod_{j=1}^J p_j^{e_j-1} \sum_{l_j=1}^{p_j}  1_{gcd(l_j,p_j) = gcd(l_j+m,p_j)=1} = \prod_{j=1}^J p_j^{e_j-1} (p_j-1-1_{p_j \, \nmid\, m})$$ $$ = \prod_{p^e\| n, p | m} p^{e-1}(p-2)\prod_{p^e\| n, p \,\nmid\, m} p^{e-1}(p-1)$$